# Interpretation of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, summation, random-variables

What would be the physical meanings of sum of two random variables? For example if $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables which show filps of coins, what would $X+Y$ represent?

Comment: You can only add if the r.v.s take values in a space where adding them makes sense. For example you can make sense of the sum of the results of rolling 2 dice.

Comment: As @Ian said, the sum needs to be defined. For example, you may map heads to 1 and tails to 0. Then, $X+Y$ would be the number of heads that occurred in two coins flips.

Comment: Ok. suppose we have two standard normal i.i.d r.v.s $X_1$ and $X_2$. Then what would their sum be interpreted? (And we know, we do add standard normal r.v.s)

Comment: Are you comfortable with measure-theoreic probability? If so, the sum is just the sum of two measurable functions.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not. Could you please elaborate?